# I see my 2nd GPT hdd partitions but not the 1st drive's

Tags: partitioning, gpt, gparted

I have 2 hdds in my laptop. I had them all converted to UEFI.  one day I notice one has reverted to MBR.  I used EaseUS to initially convert them. I went back to EaseUS when I noted the reversal on the boot drive.  Apparently their software wants Windows system on the same drive as the boot drive and when I had to replace the hdd for failure I moved the location of Windows System to the 2nd drive which somehow caused the reversal.

Today I decided to finish what I just new was going to be a problem.  I decided to use Xbuntu to move the OS to the 1st drive also creating a multi-boot system at the same time which I haven't had since the drive failure occurred. I guess I could have moved the boot partition possibly easier but I didn't think of it at the time.

I attempted to use the gparted, that's included with the Xbuntu installation, which I had already created on a flash drive.  But there was a problem with extended partition that existed on the drive. gparted would only allow 4 partitions including the EFI and so I wasn't able to setup the partions I wanted because it was still a GPT drive.   I was going to have to load up the Xbuntu system to be able to fix the problem or so I thought.

I had to install gdisk to complete the conversion which was not supposed to be destructive.  It took mere seconds to change to GPT.  When I checked the drive it showed MBR as "Protective",the 2nd and 3rd entries showed "not present" and the last showed GPT present".  Perfect.

Since gdisk was not user friendly like gparted I changed back to gparted to setup my partions.  However, like some other users that reported missing partitions I too had fallen into a similar situation.  But they seemed to be having problems because they changed the way the disk was connected to their computers.  I have not.

Using fdisk and lsblk I am able to see the partiions I cannot see in gparted.  I can even access data on the partions. But the total drive size isn't right in gparted.  Both hdds are 500gb drives yet gparted shows the 1st drive with only 298gbs.

fdisk shows my sector size as (logical/physical) 512 bytes/ 4096 bytes.  Based on what I've read most people are fine just by reconnecting the drive to the orginal device.  Mine hasn't changed as I said earlier.

The ugliness is that my 2nd drive is the same as the first but no partitions are missing in gparted for that 2nd drive.  Just to add maybe worthless info all my USB  connected drives show 512 bytes / 512 bytes but my backup 3tb drive has I/O size (minimal/optimal) of 4096 bytes / 33553920 bytes that's the only other anomoly but it too is accessible.  All drives are listed as GPT.

Why can I not see the missing partitions on my 1st drive but I can on my 2nd?  And how do I get them back so that the 1st drive is working like the 2nd?

Comment: "Why can I not see the missing partitions on my 1st drive but I can on my 2nd?" - I would assume the reason you cannot see the partitions is due to the fact you deleted them. As for getting them back, software like Test Disk, might be able to do reverse the modification to the partition table.  However, there is no guarantee the data on those partitions, can be recovered.

Comment: Did you do a backup before attempting dangerous disk operations?

Comment: Please read what I write.  I don't want to waste your time or mine.

I didn't delete anything. I stated that gparted accounts for the space used by the **unviewable partitions**.  I can access the data using file manager and other apps but obviously there's a partition or gparted problem that makes one drive able to show these partitions but not the other.

I backup my data everyday.  

Regards